# "SELECT * FROM cf" only returning indexed columns in Cassandra using Helenus for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql, helenus

I am new to Cassandra, so I might be missing something very simple.

I started off with a simple nodejs application that retrieves and displays all rows from a columnfamily. And if I run the following:

```
pool.connect(function(err, keyspace){
        if(err){
          throw(err);
        } else {
            pool.cql("SELECT * FROM tweets", function(err, results){
                console.log( err, results );
                datatext = results;
                socket.emit('tweets',datatext);
            });
        }
    });
```

All I get are the data for the first two columns, which are indexed. No data from other columns are shown. Whereas if I login to cassandra-cli and do a `list tweets`, I see data from all columns.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: What does your columnfamily look like? And, does the same query work as expected in cqlsh?

Answer (score 0):

```
which version of CQL are you using ? and what is your table structure ?
maybe you can try this:

results.forEach(function(row){
  //each row
  row.forEach(function(name,value,ts,ttl){
    //each column
    console.log(name,value,ts,ttl);
  });
});
```